# How to Generate a Roster Plan for an Organisation with Multiple Location?

Tags: sql, auto-generate

I'm new to Database, Can any one help to prepare Roster in database. And it should be generate for every week. 
Conditions Are:

1. Based on 3 Shifts per a day.
2. Based on Gender. (Ladies should be worked for Day shifts only).
3. Based on different Location.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding/homework service.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me..I didn't get an idea to how to do it

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)